# React Native QRCodeScanner not scanning QRCode on emulator

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, qr-code

I have an app that I'm working on where I'd like to test QR code scanning. One person who tested on a real device informed me that the app doesn't scan a QR code for him and instead just hangs.

I uploaded a real QR Code into the android emulator scene (see image) and I've been trying to figure out if there is some kind of trigger to make the app "scan" the code on the emulator, or if the lack of scanning is actually the error I'm trying to fix. It behaves just like a camera and never scans the code. I'm using [this](https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner) react QR scanner.

[[image]]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmNz3.png)

Everything I've seen online is leading me to believe that it should just "pick up" the qr code without having to do anything. Is this the case on the emulator, or are there some key mappings I should know about?

The QR scanner library that I'm using has an issue with deprecated PropTypes (check out the issues on the repo) but I've put in a patch (see comments in issues in the repo) and I thought it was working up until this point.

There are no messages/errors in the android studio logs.

Any advice is appreciated! Thanks.